# Next JS - How to force update the application or reload the cached JS files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, next.js

I'm using the Next JS application. Whenever I deployed new code to production, end-user did not get updated to the latest version and always site served from the **browser cache**. then I need to inform the users to clear cache or use incognito mode to get the latest code.

Is there any better way to clear cache in the user browser, (or) Auto-update cache whenever we deployed the new code in production in the next JS?

Tried the following steps:

1. Disabling e-tag - Not working.
2. Reload the page(`window.reload`) - Not working.

Attached the image in which I tried the new next js app.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uozZC.png)

Comment: That's not the default behaviour for Next.js apps. What hosting platform are you deploying your app to?

Comment: @juliomalves Thanks for the reply. We are using **AWS EKS Cluster**. Kubernetes Concept.